# mpl_toolkits.axisartist: Moving label of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am currently trying to create some graphs for my thesis.
For that I need to move the label of the x-axes to the very right.
Becaused i needed to add some arrows to my axes, I used "mpl_toolkits.axisartist".

I think to move the label I have to use "axislabel ha" described on this site (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axis_artist.html) but I somehow can't make it work.

I tried something like: "axisartist.axis_artist.AxisLabel.set_ha('right')" and "axax.axis['y=0'].set_axislabel(ha='right')", but those were not correct.

Thank you for your help.
Regards Jonas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as axisartist

x_ow = [1, 2, 3]                                                 
npv_ow_sz1 = [-10000, 20000, 30000] 
npv_ow_sz2 = [-20000, 50000, 60000]                              
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))   
axax = axisartist.Subplot(fig, 111) 
fig.add_axes(axax) 
axax.axis["y=0"] = axax.new_floating_axis(nth_coord=0, value=0)         ### x-Achse auf y=0 setzen       
axax.axis["y=0"].set_axisline_style("->", size = 1.5)                   ### Pfeil an x-Achse bei y=0 anfügen
axax.axis["left"].set_axisline_style("->", size = 1.5)                  ### Pfeil an y-Achse anfügen
axax.axis["bottom"].set_visible(False)                                  ### Untere Achse entfernen
axax.axis["right"].set_visible(False)                                   ### Rechte Achse entfernen    
axax.axis["top"].set_visible(False)                                     ### Obere Achse entfernen

plt.plot(x_ow, npv_ow_sz1, 'ro-', label='$\mathregular{NPV_{O/W,Sz1}}$')    
plt.plot(x_ow, npv_ow_sz2, 'ro-', label='$\mathregular{NPV_{O/W,Sz2}}$')    
line1, line2 = plt.gca().lines              
line1.set_linewidth(1) 
line2.set_linewidth(1) 
plt.setp(line1, color='lightcoral', linestyle='--')      
plt.setp(line2, color='indianred', linestyle='--')

plt.ylabel('NPV [€]', fontsize=12)                                     
axax.axis["y=0"].set_label("P [kWp]")

plt.legend(loc='upper right')                                          
plt.title('ABC', pad=20, fontsize=14)
plt.grid('True')                                                        
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I tried the code below according to https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axis_artist.AxisLabel.html

```py
ax.axis["x"].label.set_position([100, 0])
```

but it's useless. I don't know why and if there exists better answers.
The simplest way is don't show the label and add text yourself.

```py
ax.text(-0.5, 1.35, r'$\omega$(rad)', fontsize=20)
ax.text(3.14, -0.25, 'time(s)', fontsize=20)
```

Comment: I met the issue as well, and what you said is really helpful!